# Exchange Server 2013 on Server 2012 R2 Exchange Management Shell cant connect to Exchange Server

Tags: exchange, powershell

so i have a problem. Can't connect to exchange server via exchange management shell or powershell. heres what i got: http://prnt.sc/daacqb . I did a lot of searches on google, tried different methods but still nothing..Can you recommend me something to make it work?

Comment: WinRM is setup to use kerberos authentication and it is failing. Do you have the correct username and password? Are you in the same domain?

Comment: Yes, am in the same domain and i got AD administrator username and password

Comment: What about the Exchange Roles? Organisation Management? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335087%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Default Group Access
During setup, WinRM creates the local group WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__. WinRM then restricts remote access to any user that is not a member of either the local administration group or the WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__ group. You can add a local user, domain user, or domain group to WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__ by typing net localgroup WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__ /add <domain>\<username> at the command prompt. Optionally, you can use the Group Policy to add a user to the group. From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384295(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Okay i added my users to this group, now how i can login with them into exchange management?

Comment: Are they members of the Exchange Role Based Access Control group Organisation Management?

Comment: Get-RoleGroupMember "Organization Management"

Comment: Got 2 users: http://prntscr.com/dacje3

Comment: Can those two users access Exchange Management? Not using WinRM. They should have the keys to the castle with Organisation Management rights.

Comment: do you talk about if the users can acces management over http://<servername>/ecp ? yes they can if i understanded question correctly

Comment: Ok, so permission to Exchange is ok. Sorry, above question should have been access to the Exchange Management Console. Does the WinRM connection using the Exchange Management Shell work? I don't have Exchange on my test domain so can't test unfortunately.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dacoxn i think is still the same...Maybe somehow its possible to authenticate with basic authentication, not with kerberos?

Comment: This link discusses WinRM troubleshooting: http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/understanding-and-troubleshooting-winrm-connection-and-authentication-a-thrill-seekers-guide-to-adventure

Comment: the MSDN link from earlier also talks about basic authentication. This will pass usernames and passwords in clear text so isn't recommended.

Comment: Meh i tried almost everything but still no progress..anyone else how to pass kerberos authentication?:S

Comment: I spotted that <servername>/powershell via browser i also cant connect. all of my users are rejected. What user should i use to access powershell via virtual directory?

Answer (score 1):

So after 3 days of google searches i found my problem. the problem was that in IIS physical path of PowerShell was C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\PowerShell . After this changing to C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\ClientAccess\PowerShell all problems gone and now am able to connect to exchange server. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!